# What's the differences between Boundless and Osgeo versions?

Tags: java, geotools

On the `maven repository`, I see two distributions of geotools shown :
– One, called Boundless, offers the versions `19.0` and `19.1`.
– The other one, called Osgeo, `18.4` and `19.2`.

Despite searching over the Internet, I haven't been able to figure what their differences are, and why two distributions exist.

I am currently compiling with the boundless one. Should I change?

Comment: This is the only thing I could figured out for your problem, I don't know if it's useful or if you already seen it : https://wiki.52north.org/Documentation/GeoTools

Comment: I believed that the OsGeo one was discontiued as sometimes its happens with some distributions, but now that I see it taking a greater version number than the boundless one... What are they for, these two distributions ? One of these must have a specific goal, an ability that the second one doesn't have, but I can't figure which one.

Comment: "GeoTools has a development version and one or more stable versions active at any given time" so that can explain the differences in the versions.
But for the differences of the Boundless and Osgeo distributions, I don't know...

Comment: Now the repositories moved to https://www.osgeo.org/foundation-news/new-osgeo-repo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in the [documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/maven/repositories.html):

> GeoTools itself is deployed to the following repositories:
>
> http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/ - geotools release repository
>   http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/snapshot - geotools SNAPSHOT repository
>
> Or you can make use of the following cache:
>
> https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main - boundless repository acting as a cache of the above

When I check now, I can see 19.2 and 20-RC in both repositories, while the SNAPSHOT jars are only available on boundless' repository. So unless you need to be on the cutting edge of development I would use the OSGEO repository.

The [Open Source Geospatial Foundation (OSGeo)](http://osgeo.org) is a not-for-profit organization whose mission is to foster global adoption of open geospatial technology by being an inclusive software foundation devoted to an open philosophy and participatory community driven development. The foundation provides infrastructure to support osgeo projects like [GeoTools](http://geotools.org).

[Boundless](https://boundlessgeo.com/) helps reduce the cost and time of deploying and managing geospatial software with a scalable, open GIS platform – including Server, Exchange, Desktop and Connect – and a powerful ecosystem of geospatial knowledge, tools and resources. As part of their business program they provide support to the GeoTools and [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) build process including CI and SNAPSHOT hosting.

Comment: Both of these Boundless repository URLs are unreachable (server not found). Are they still correct? Is there a page you can link to on Boundless' server that has the current Maven repo URL?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226545/geotools-lib-suddenly-disappear-from-repository