# Geotools lib suddenly disappear from repository

Tags: java, spring, maven, geotools

Yesterday when I tried building a common service, it yield an error

> 253 Caused by:
>   org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: The
>   following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.geotools:gt-main:jar:21.2, org.geotools:gt-epsg-wkt:jar:21.2,
>   org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:jar:21.2: Could not find artifact
>   org.geotools:gt-main:jar:21.2 in spring-milestones
>   (https://repo.spring.io/milestone)

It was success just a few hours ago, before the issue occurs. No change has been made for a long while.

We use several repository, one of them is http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools. But it seems the URL is down now. No idea when and why it was down - I can't find anything on the osgeo.org home page.

Is there anyway to get warnings about this kind of issue? What should I do to prevent the problem from happening again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The repository moved, and we were unable to get maven to handle a redirect.

See http://geotoolsnews.blogspot.com/2020/04/change-to-maven-repositories.html?m=1 for more details.

So now you need this in your `pom.xml` files:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Or you can add this to your `~/.m2/settings.xml` file:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>osgeo-release</id>
    <name>OSGeo Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
    <mirrorOf>osgeo</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
  <mirror>
    <id>geoserver-releases</id>
    <name>Boundless Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/Geoserver-releases/</url>
    <mirrorOf>boundless</mirrorOf>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```