# issue locating boudless geo repo while building marklogic geotools plugin

Tags: geoserver, marklogic-8, geotools

Not sure why we are not able to build **marklogic-geotools-plugin-master** getting the below exception. Gradle not able to locate the **repo.boundlessgeo.com**.

Do we need to add any configuration before building this jar file
https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-geotools-plugin

- What went wrong:

````
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.geotools:gt-geojson:22.0.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve org.geotools:gt-geojson:22.0.
         > Could not get resource 'https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/geotools/gt-geojson/22.0/gt-geojson-22.0.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/geotools/gt-geojson/22.0/gt-geojson-22.0.pom'.
               > repo.boundlessgeo.com```
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geotools lib suddenly disappear from repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226545/geotools-lib-suddenly-disappear-from-repository)

Comment: Yes. It helped and able to build the jar file